Can you grey out picklist unless you select specific field from another picklist?
Under my Cases, I have a custom picklist labeled "Case Category *Non-Hotline". I also have *Non-hotline as a picklist field in Case Type. Here is my question:
Is there a way to have the Case Category *Non-Hotline picklist only be selectable if you chose the *Non-Hotline field under Type?
Thanks in advance for the assistance,
T-roy


https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/picklist_admin/picklist_admin_manage

If this is a standard page, then this should be achievable by "Dependent Picklist".   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_dependent_fields.htm&type=5
If this is Custom, then you will have to share your code, in order for us, to check this.

Thank you for the info. That is exactly what I needed and it worked as expected.
